# Unit testing in Cake2: How to mock AppModel function?

Tags: php, unit-testing, cakephp, cakephp-2.x

I want to test my CategoriesController and for that I need to mock a method of the AppModel. I stick to the [Cake docs](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/testing.html#using-mocks-with-testaction) but I think my case is slightly different since the Category model has no relation to the AppModel but inherits from it.

app/Model/AppModel.php includes:

```
<?php
App::uses('Model', 'Model');

class AppModel extends Model
{

    public function storeId()
    {
        return Configure::read('storeId');
    }
}
```

app/Test/Case/Controller/CategoriesControllerTest.php includes:

```
<?php
App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class CategoriesControllerTest extends ControllerTestCase
{
    public $fixtures = [...]
    public function testView() {
            $Categories = $this->generate('Categories', [
                'models' => [
                    'AppModel' => [
                        'storeId'
                    ],
                ]
            ]);
            $Categories->AppModel
                ->method('storeId')
                ->will($this->returnValue(17));

            $result = $this->testAction('/categories/view/1700007',
                ['return' => 'vars']
            );  
    }
}
```

This results in an error

> Error: Call to a member function method() on null in...

The background:
I need to mock the storeId method because during the view() call in the CategoriesController a query is manipulated by a method in the AppModel, which uses the storeId() function to determine which is the active store.

Comment: Normally you don't use the `AppModel` class directly, but concrete subclasses thereof, so why not mock the method there? Mocking a parent class isn't going to work anyways, given that mocking works by extending the original class.

Comment: that doesn't sound good. I use the AppModel for general stuff, which has to be done nearly before or after every call. for example, there is the beforeFind method which I cannot mock in the inherting models because they have their own before- and afterFind methods..

Comment: Sounds like there is a probability of a bad architecture. Consider moving your generic stuff to a behavior and test / mock that behavior? There is no way to give a better advice without know whats going on inside the app.

Comment: Okay, to explain it shortly: The application is a multi shop system. The beforeFind method in the AppModel extends many queries with something like "AND <model_name>.store_id = <store_id>", in this case the Category model. I thought the AppModel's beforeFind would be the right place for that.
But yeah, maybe I'll have to take a look if moving this to a behaviour could be better.